# Parsing a datetime string when reading in data with pandas

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, pandas

I am struggling with reading in a datetime string and storing it as a variable. I have a block of data that looks like this:

```
2011-11-01 05:20:00 00:10:00
#    z  speed    dir      W   sigW       bck   error 
30   4.76  238.9   0.01   0.13  7.56E+06       0
40   5.24  237.1  -0.05   0.12  5.99E+06       0
50   6.33  236.6  -0.01   0.12  7.24E+06       0
60   7.06  237.3  -0.01   0.12  9.15E+06       0
70   7.85  238.2  -0.02   0.13  8.47E+06       0
80   8.85  237.3  -0.03   0.14  1.05E+07     256

2011-11-01 05:30:00 00:10:00
#    z  speed    dir      W   sigW       bck   error 
30   4.40  234.8   0.08   0.12  1.33E+07       0
40   5.07  234.2   0.11   0.12  5.82E+06       0
50   5.75  234.3   0.12   0.12  6.61E+06       0
60   6.56  232.4   0.08   0.13  6.39E+06       0
70   7.22  233.2   0.10   0.13  5.64E+06       0
80   8.15  235.3   0.12   0.14  5.87E+06     256
```

My code works great for what I need to do except for reading in the datetime string because I keep getting an error. Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import glob
import datetime

```
def parse_date(string):
    # Split the string into year/month/date, time, and seconds
    split_string = string.split()
    # get year month and date
    year = split_string[0].split('-')[0]
    month = split_string[0].split('-')[1]
    date = split_string[0].split('-')[2]

    # get hour minute second
    hour = split_string[1].split(':')[0]
    mm = split_string[1].split(':')[1]
    second = split_string[1].split(':')[2]

    return datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(date), hour=int(hour), minute=int(mm), second=int(second))

filename = glob.glob('1511??.mnd')
data_nov15_hereford = pd.DataFrame()
frames = []
dates = []
counter = 1
for i in filename:
    f_nov15_hereford = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows = 32, sep='\s+')
    for line in f_nov15_hereford:
        if line.startswith('20'):
            print line
            dates.append(parse_date(line))
            counter = 0
        else:
            counter += 1 
    frames.append(f_nov15_hereford) 
data_nov15_hereford = pd.concat(frames,ignore_index=True)
data_nov15_hereford = data_nov15_hereford.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

My error is with my parsing function:

```
     15     # get hour minute second
---> 16     hour = split_string[1].split(':')[0]
     17     mm = split_string[1].split(':')[1]
     18     second = split_string[1].split(':')[2]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

If anyone could help me figure out this error that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel by making your own date parsing function.   Utilize the `datetime.datetime.strptime` function from the standard lib.

Pass the date string and the format of the string to the `strptime` function.

```
import datetime
date_string = '2011-11-01 05:20:00'
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

It looks like you're dealing with a string that has a date and time along with an interval?  You can parse the date, time and interval separately:

```
original_string = '2011-11-01 05:20:00 00:10:00'
date_string, time_string, interval_string = original_string.split()
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
time_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, ' %H:%M:%S')
interval_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(interval_string, '%H:%M:%S')
```

I would review the [docs for parsing and formatting dates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

Comment: It's weird because when I put this first suggestion into my code I get an error: ValueError: time data '2015-11-01' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: If your string is simply `'2015-11-01'`, then the format is `'%Y-%m-%d '`.

Comment: `%Y` represents the four digit year, `%m` represents the two-digit, zero-padded month, `%d ` represents the two-digit, zero-padded day.

Comment: But if you look at my data there is more to the string with h, m, s but for some reason my code isn't grabbing the entire line. Maybe that is because of my startswith part of my loop? Hmm so this should work I think my problem now is with how I am grabbing my string

Comment: Depending on how pandas is reading the csv, there might be string literals trailing the date string such as a carriage return which is represented like so `\r`.  Instead of `print line`, try `print repr(line)` and it might show you something like `'2011-11-01 05:20:00\r'`.  If it does, you will have to replace that `\r`.

Comment: `string = '2011-11-01 05:20:00\r'`; `string = string.replace('\r', '')`

Comment: When I do this I actually don't get the \r.  I think my only issue  is that when I say to grab the line.startswith('20') it is only grabbing '2015-11-01' it isn't grabbing the rest of the line that includes the time. Any ideas on how to get this to work? if not that is fine just wondering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104000/discussion-between-chishaku-and-meghan).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply get the datetime string

```
thestring = "2011-11-01 05:20:00 00:10:00"`
```

then convert to time

```
aa = thestring.split(" ")
t =datetime.datetime.strptime(aa[0]+" "+aa[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and finally access the hour, minutes, etc. E.g.,

t.hour